# Rails engine path helper doesn't include mount namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I have created a rails engine which I'm mounting in the main application's routes.rb:

```
mount OsuAuth::Engine => '/admin'
```

I would like to reference a users path helper defined in the engine from my main application, for which I tried:

```
<%= link_to 'Users', osu_auth.users_path %>
```

However this generates a path to `/users` instead of the working path of `/admin/users`.

Running `rake routes` also outputs the route without the /admin namespace:

```
users GET    /users(.:format)                osu_auth/users#index
```

This seems odd to me. What happened to the /admin namespace where I mounted the engine? How can I get generate the correct path?

Comment: did you ever come to a resolution for this, or workaround?

Comment: the workaround I ended up using was this: `<%= link_to 'Users', "#{osu_auth_path}#{osu_auth.users_path}" %>`. Not very clean in my opinion, but seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `namespace` directive:

```
namespace :admin do
  mount OsuAuth::Engine
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. This complains about missing the mount point, and when adding '/admin' as the mount point it gives me a path of /admin/admin/users. If I add the mount point of '/' it removes all namespaces and gives me he path /users.